# how to group xml elements in java by attributes

Tags: java, xml, domparser

I have a requirement for grouping XML elements with same attribute in Java.

Below is my updated input:

```
<root>
 <Slots date="2015-11-17">
    <TimePeriod value="8-17">
        <ContractorAvailable ContractorID="H4CONT07">
            <GroupId>298451</GroupId>
            <OfferToken>10315009</OfferToken>
            <Capacity>99</Capacity>
        </ContractorAvailable>
    </TimePeriod>
</Slots>
<Slots date="2015-11-17">
    <TimePeriod value="8-17">
        <ContractorAvailable ContractorID="H4CONT07">
            <GroupId>298452</GroupId>
            <OfferToken>10315009</OfferToken>
            <Capacity>99</Capacity>
        </ContractorAvailable>
    </TimePeriod>
</Slots>
 <Slots date="2015-11-18">
    <TimePeriod value="2-8">
        <ContractorAvailable ContractorID="H4CONT07">
            <GroupId>298451</GroupId>
            <OfferToken>10315009</OfferToken>
            <Capacity>99</Capacity>
        </ContractorAvailable>
    </TimePeriod>
</Slots>
<Slots date="2015-11-18">
    <TimePeriod value="2-8">
        <ContractorAvailable ContractorID="H4CONT07">
            <GroupId>298452</GroupId>
            <OfferToken>10315009</OfferToken>
            <Capacity>99</Capacity>
        </ContractorAvailable>
    </TimePeriod>
</Slots>
```

I need the output as below:

```
 <root>
 <Slots date="2015-11-17">
    <TimePeriod value="8-17">
        <ContractorAvailable ContractorID="H4CONT07">
            <GroupId>298451</GroupId>
            <OfferToken>10315009</OfferToken>
            <Capacity>99</Capacity>
        </ContractorAvailable>
        <ContractorAvailable ContractorID="H4CONT07">
            <GroupId>298452</GroupId>
            <OfferToken>10315009</OfferToken>
            <Capacity>99</Capacity>
        </ContractorAvailable>
    </TimePeriod>
 </Slots>
 <Slots date="2015-11-18">
    <TimePeriod value="2-8">
        <ContractorAvailable ContractorID="H4CONT07">
            <GroupId>298451</GroupId>
            <OfferToken>10315009</OfferToken>
            <Capacity>99</Capacity>
        </ContractorAvailable>
        <ContractorAvailable ContractorID="H4CONT07">
            <GroupId>298452</GroupId>
            <OfferToken>10315009</OfferToken>
            <Capacity>99</Capacity>
        </ContractorAvailable>
    </TimePeriod>
</Slots>
</root>
```

I tried something like the below:

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
     if( node!= null && node.getLength() > 0)  {


         for(int i=0;i<node.getLength();i=i+1)
         {  
               Node slots = node.item(i);
               set.add(slots.getAttributes().getNamedItem("date").getNodeValue());
         } 
    }
     System.out.println("slots dates are  --- **** "+ set);
     ArrayList<Node> deleteList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    for(String date  : set)
     {  System.out.println("slots dates is --- **** "+ "2015-11-18");
           Node remainingNode = null;
           for(int i=0;i<node.getLength();i=i+1)
           {  
                 Node slotnode = node.item(i);
                 if( slotnode.getAttributes() != null && slotnode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("date")!= null && "2015-11-18".equals(slotnode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("date").getNodeValue()))
                 {System.out.println("inside time 18");
                       if(remainingNode == null)
                             remainingNode = slotnode;
                       else {
                             NodeList nodeps = slotnode.getChildNodes();
                             for(int j=0;j<nodeps.getLength();j=i+1) {
                                   remainingNode.appendChild(nodeps.item(j));
                             }
                             deleteList.add(slotnode);
                       }
                 }
           }  
           NodeList nodesItems = doc1.getElementsByTagName("root"); 
           nodesItems.item(0).appendChild(remainingNode);
```

I tried with using Dom parser, but I was not able to do. I am new to XML, searched everywhere but didn't find anything, Can anyone please help me in this.
Note:I can't use JAXB for this solution.

yes i have group Slots by date and then additionally by TimePeriod value.
XSLT is not supported by tool which i am using

Comment: Consider to do the grouping in a language like XSLT 2.0 (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples) or XQuery 3 (http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-group-by) which on Java are supported for instance by Saxon 9, available in an open source version from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: Which Java version do you use?

Comment: Can you provide a well-formed XML sample with a single root element? Do you need to group `Slots` by `date` and then additionally by `TimePeriod value`? Or is that value the same for all `Slots` with the same `date`?

Comment: Are you able to use the Java 8 grouping?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your XML file is not well-formed. This is the well-formed version:

```
<root>
<Slots date="2015-11-17">
    <TimePeriod value="8-17">
        <ContractorAvailable ContractorID="H4CONT07">
            <GroupId>298451</GroupId>
            <OfferToken>10315009</OfferToken>
            <Capacity>99</Capacity>
        </ContractorAvailable>
    </TimePeriod>
</Slots>
<Slots date="2015-11-17">
    <TimePeriod value="8-17">
        <ContractorAvailable ContractorID="H4CONT07">
            <GroupId>298452</GroupId>
            <OfferToken>10315009</OfferToken>
            <Capacity>99</Capacity>
        </ContractorAvailable>
    </TimePeriod>
</Slots>
</root>
```

This is an example to show how to access your data in your XML file:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;

public class XMLParser {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        try {
        File fXmlFile = new File("C:/test.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element in this XML file is :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ContractorAvailable");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(i);     
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());    
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println("Contractor ID : " + eElement.getAttribute("ContractorID"));
            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
}
```

Result will be like this:

[image: The result]

When you have access to your data, you can make a new XML file.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, I think this is an easy job for XSLT 2.0 (available for Java for instance using Saxon 9.6 HE from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE respectively http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.6/SaxonHE9-6-0-7J.zip/download) and the following XSLT code:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Slots" group-by="@date">
                <Slots date="{current-grouping-key()}">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/TimePeriod" group-by="@value">
                        <TimePeriod value="{current-grouping-key()}">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/ContractorAvailable"/>
                        </TimePeriod>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </Slots>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

If you want to do grouping in Java, the Java 8 has support for that but the DOM is not really the right data structure, so you would need to build a `List<Element>` first, then group and construct and new DOM:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class DOMGroupBy1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document inputDoc = db.parse("input.xml");

        Document outputDoc = db.newDocument();
        outputDoc.appendChild(outputDoc.createElement("root"));

        NodeList domSlots = inputDoc.getElementsByTagName("Slots");

        List<Element> slots = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < domSlots.getLength(); i++) {
            slots.add((Element) domSlots.item(i));
        }

        List<Element> groups
                = slots
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(slot -> slot.getAttribute("date")))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(entry -> {
                    Element newSlot = outputDoc.createElement("Slots");
                    newSlot.setAttribute("date", entry.getKey());
                    entry
                            .getValue()
                            .stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(slot -> ((Element) slot.getElementsByTagName("TimePeriod").item(0)).getAttribute("value")))
                            .entrySet()
                            .forEach(time -> {
                                Element timeEl = outputDoc.createElement("TimePeriod");
                                timeEl.setAttribute("value", time.getKey());
                                newSlot.appendChild(timeEl);
                                time.getValue().forEach(el -> {
                                    NodeList cas = el.getElementsByTagName("ContractorAvailable");
                                    for (int j = 0; j < cas.getLength(); j++) {
                                        timeEl.appendChild(outputDoc.importNode(cas.item(j), true));
                                    }

                                });
                            });

                    return newSlot;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        LSSerializer serializer = ((DOMImplementationLS) db.getDOMImplementation()).createLSSerializer();
        serializer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", true);

        groups.forEach(slot -> outputDoc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(slot));

        System.out.println(serializer.writeToString(outputDoc));  // could of course write a file here instead with e.g. serializer.writeToURI(outputDoc, new File("result.xml").toURI().toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Thanks for your answer, but  my tool doesnt support Java 1.8 , can you please provide answer in java 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers, however I was able to grouping with the following code. Hope it might help for others looking for the same.

```
 package beans;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class Grouping {


/**
 * Gets the first child element of a node.
 * @param node the node to get the child from
 * @return the first element child of the given Node
 * 
 */
public static Element getFirstChildElement(Node node)
{
    node = node.getFirstChild();
    while (node != null && node.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
    {
        node = node.getNextSibling();
    }
    return (Element)node;
}

/**
 * Groups the Given Nodes based on the tag value. Tag should be present in as attribute in the root tag.
 * @ NodeList  List of Nodes for which grouping needs to be done
 * @String     Group Tag name based on its values, the nodes will be grouped
 * @return  boolean true/false.
 * 
 */

public static boolean groupNodes(NodeList slotNodes, String strGroupTag)
{

    // Start checking the unique Values for grouping
            TreeSet<String> slotdates = new TreeSet<String>();
            if( slotNodes!= null && slotNodes.getLength() > 0)  {


                for(int i=0;i<slotNodes.getLength();i++)
                {  
                     Node slots = slotNodes.item(i);

                    if(slots != null && slots.getAttributes() != null)
                     {
                        String strDate = slots.getAttributes().getNamedItem(strGroupTag).getNodeValue();
                        slotdates.add(strDate);
                     }                              
                } 
            }
    // Ends :  checking the unique Values for grouping

    // Starts Grouping based on dates
            ArrayList<Node> deleteSlotList = new ArrayList<Node>();
            for(String slotdate  : slotdates)
            {  
                Node remainingSlotNode = null;
                for(int i=0;i<slotNodes.getLength();i++)
                {  
                    Node slotnode = slotNodes.item(i);

                    if( slotnode.getAttributes() != null && slotnode.getAttributes().getNamedItem(strGroupTag)!= null)
                    {
                        String strDateValue = slotnode.getAttributes().getNamedItem(strGroupTag).getNodeValue();

                        if(strDateValue != null && strDateValue.equalsIgnoreCase(slotdate))
                        {
                            if(remainingSlotNode == null)
                            {
                                remainingSlotNode = slotnode;
                            }
                            else {
                                Node NodeTime = getFirstChildElement(slotnode);
                                if(NodeTime != null)
                                {

                                    remainingSlotNode.appendChild(NodeTime);

                                }
                                deleteSlotList.add(slotnode);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }  

                slotNodes.item(0).getParentNode().appendChild(remainingSlotNode);                               

            }

            for(Node deletedNode: deleteSlotList)
            {
                deletedNode.getParentNode().removeChild(deletedNode);

            }
            // Ends Grouping based on dates
            return true;
}

public static DOMSource groupingUtil(String xml) throws TransformerException, SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml))); 
    NodeList slotNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Slots");



    if(groupNodes(slotNodes, "date"))
    {
        slotNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Slots");
        for(int i=0;i<slotNodes.getLength();i++)
        {
            Node slot = slotNodes.item(i);
            NodeList timeNodes = slot.getChildNodes();
            groupNodes(timeNodes, "value");
        }
    }       

    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();  
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");                  
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());  

    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    transformer.transform(source, result);

    return source;
}
}
```